# Why is the dative case used here?

Tags: meaning, preposition, grammatical-case

> … meine Mutter richtete *mir* das Bett *auf dem* Balkon.

*auf* + dative → It is *on* the table.

*auf* + accusative → I put it *onto* the table.

In the example, I thought, the latter would be apt. But why isn't it in the accusative case?

And why is *mir* used? Is it an ethical dative?

Answer (score 7):

I agree with @BjörnFriedrich in every detail, but I would like to put more emphasis on the misunderstanding-prone issues here.

### *richten*: 1) to point; 2) to prepare

You thought that the verb would be *etw. auf etw. richten* ('to point sth. in the direction of sth.'). If that was the case, *das Bett auf **den** Balkon richten* would be grammatically correct.

But, the verb here is *etw. (her)richten* ('to prepare sth.'), and *auf dem Balkon* is **not** a part of the verb, but is an adverbial determination of the place. That means the phrase *auf dem Balkon* means just *on the balcony*, and thus is dative. The translation would be *my mother prepared the bed on the balcony...*

### *mir*: for me

*...for me*. The case of *mir* is not the *dativus ethicus* (ethical dative), but the *dativus commodi*. It says who profits from an action; in this case, for whom the bed is prepared (who enjoys the prepared bed later).

Answer (score 5):

The preposition [*auf*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/auf#auf_(Deutsch)) works in two ways: It demands the accusative case when it refers to a direction, and it demands the dative case when it refers to a location.

#### Accusative

In the following example, the bed is moved onto the balcony. Therefore, *auf* refers to a direction:

> Meine Mutter stellte mir das Bett *auf den Balkon*.
>
> (My mother put the bed for me *onto the balcony*.)

#### Dative

This is different in the following example, where the bed is prepared on the balcony. Here, *auf* refers to the bed as a location:

> Meine Mutter richtete *mir* das Bett *auf dem Balkon* (her).
>
> (My mother prepared the bed *for me* *on the balcony*.)

Notice that the verb is actually [*herrichten*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/herrichten). But in southern regions the prefix *her-* is often omitted, resulting in [*richten*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/richten) (see meanings [3] and [4]). Still, it is essential to not confuse it with the noun *Richtung* (*direction*), as this might lead to a wrong association with the accusative case.

#### Regarding *mir*

The pronoun [*mir*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mir) is in dative case, too, because in German this is one way to indicate the receiver of the action. In our example, the bed is not prepared for anyone, but for me. The advantage of using *mir* is that you need no additional preposition. Still, you can use a preposition, *für*, but then the pronoun must be in accusative case, i. e., *mich*:

> Meine Mutter richtete *für mich* das Bett *auf dem Balkon* (her).
>
> (My mother prepared the bed *for me* *on the balcony*.)

Comment: I dont get it. the only difference is the verbs...whats it about richete that makes auf require the dative case? richete means direct so...auf seems to require accusative whhichh is about motion.

Comment: @user21669, actually, the verb is *herrichten*. I edited my answer to clarify this.

Comment: *Richten* by itself can have the meaning *to prepare*: https://www.dwds.de/wb/richten#d-1-5

Comment: What I was trying to say is that it is unnecessary to mention *herrichten* at all. Furthermore, I believe that it is wrong to claim that *richten* in the sense *to prepare* is derived from *herrichten*.

Comment: @DavidVogt: For me, a northeastern German, *richten* is short for *hinrichten* (to execute, to kill). Whenever I read it, the first thing I envision is a rope or a guillotine, until my inner voice says "Wait, this doesn't make sense here. It's certainly not *hinrichten* but what southerners say when they mean *herrichten*." This alone makes it necessary, in my view, to mention the difference. Furthermore, I will no longer go into nerve-wrecking discussions about what you do or do not believe irrespective of the fact that I have supported the claim with (at other times accepted) references.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich I see no reference for the claim that *richten* "to prepare" is derived from *herrichten*.

Comment: Wiktionary (all links in the answer): **herrichten:** *"\[1\] in einen ansehnlichen oder zumindest verwendbaren Zustand versetzen"*. **richten:** *"\[3\] **süddeutsch, österreichisch, schweizerisch**: etwas in Ordnung bringen, (figürlich) etwas wieder gerade biegen* and *\[4\] **süddeutsch, österreichisch, schweizerisch**: etwas zubereiten, vorbereiten"*. In short: generally with *her-*, in southern regions without *her-*. You're welcome!